# Recursive bisection search to retrieve the index of a target

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, bisection

I tried to search the index of a find with bisection algorithms

```
def bi_search(nums: List[int], find: int) -> int:
    """
    Return the index of the find 
    """
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return -1
    else:
        mid = len(nums) // 2  #testEntry
        if find == nums[mid]:
            return mid 
        if find < nums[mid]:
            sub_nums = nums[:mid]
            return bi_search(sub_nums, find)  

        if find > nums[mid]:
            sub_nums = nums[mid:]
            return bi_search(sub_nums, find) #recursive case.
```

but it does not work as expected

```
In [26]: bi_search(list(range(1000)), 777)                     
Out[26]: 4
```

It return the mid of the base case.

I noticed that a correct index could be retrieve using iteration methods as in [bisect — Array bisection algorithm — Python 3.7.3rc1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/bisect.html)

Is it possible to get a correct index in a recursive solution?

Comment: The correct index?  It's harder with your approach.  That's because in the last iteration, nums will be something like [773,774,775,776,777,778,779,780,781,782].  A recursive solution that would work would be to have a function like bi_search(nums, lower_bound, upper_bound) where you are sure that the target element is between the indices of lower_bound and upper_bound.  And you just pass nums through WITHOUT slicing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a `print()` statement to the function and use a smaller example, you can see the problem:

```
def bi_search(nums, find):
    print((nums, find))
    ...

print(bi_search(list(range(10)), 7))
```

Output:

```
([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 7)   # Looks good.
([5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 7)                  # Also good.
2                                     # Doh!
```

The problem is that you are returning the index in the **last list checked**, not the index of the **initial list**. To make your approach work, you need to pass more information through the recursive calls -- and it gets tricky.

A different approach is to pass the full list for every call, and instead adjust the lower/upper bounds for searching as you go. This also has the advantage of avoiding the creation of new lists with each call. For example:

```
def bi_search(nums, find, i = None, j = None):
    # Setup.
    N = len(nums)
    if i is None:
        i = 0
        j = N - 1
    # Base case for failure.
    if j < i:
        return None
    # Success or recurse.
    mid = (i + j) // 2
    if find == nums[mid]:
        return mid 
    elif find < nums[mid]:
        return bi_search(nums, find, i, mid - 1)
    else:
        return bi_search(nums, find, mid + 1, j)
```